# Default Tab for all users in Salesforce classic

Tags: visualforce, administration, tab

how can I set the default tabs displayed by users in an app with standard salesforce? Can I overwrite user settings?

Users continue to see extra tabs and with an order not desired by the customer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the App and check this "*Overwrite Users' Personal Custom App Customizations*" checkbox. It will override Users' tabset with App's tabset.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! but I have another problem, for the administrator I do not see one of the tabs, I checked in the profile and I saw that the tab is set as "default off" if I try to put "default on" the system shows the error: "Error: Invalid Data.
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Permission Subscribe to Dashboards: Add Recipients depends on permission (s): Subscribe to Dashboards"
the "Subscribe to dashboard" flag is false, do I have to activate it necessarily? what happens if I enable it?

Comment: I've read that this is a bug related to the release Summer 18 and  I have to open a salesforce case

Comment: Good to know that there is a new bug.